# How to use a dict to subset a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categorical-data

Say, I have given a DataFrame with most of the columns being categorical data.

```
> data.head()
  age risk     sex smoking
0  28   no    male      no
1  58   no  female      no
2  27   no    male     yes
3  26   no    male      no
4  29  yes  female     yes
```

And I would like to subset this data by a dict of key-value pairs for those categorical variables.

```
tmp = {'risk':'no', 'smoking':'yes', 'sex':'female'}
```

Hence, I would like to have the following subset.

```
data[ (data.risk == 'no') & (data.smoking == 'yes') & (data.sex == 'female')]
```

What I want to do is:

```
data[tmp]
```

What is the most python / pandas way of doing this?

---

Minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

x = Series(random.randint(0,2,50), dtype='category')
x.cat.categories = ['no', 'yes']

y = Series(random.randint(0,2,50), dtype='category')
y.cat.categories = ['no', 'yes']

z = Series(random.randint(0,2,50), dtype='category')
z.cat.categories = ['male', 'female']

a = Series(random.randint(20,60,50), dtype='category')

data = DataFrame({'risk':x, 'smoking':y, 'sex':z, 'age':a})

tmp = {'risk':'no', 'smoking':'yes', 'sex':'female'}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use [.query()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-query-method-experimental) method for this task:

```
qry = ' and '.join(["{} == '{}'".format(k,v) for k,v in tmp.items()])    

data.query(qry)
```

output:

```
   age risk     sex smoking
7   24   no  female     yes
22  43   no  female     yes
23  42   no  female     yes
25  24   no  female     yes
32  29   no  female     yes
40  34   no  female     yes
43  35   no  female     yes
```

Query string:

```
print(qry)
"sex == 'female' and risk == 'no' and smoking == 'yes'"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use list comprehension with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(123)
x = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,2,10), dtype='category')
x.cat.categories = ['no', 'yes']
y = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,2,10), dtype='category')
y.cat.categories = ['no', 'yes']
z = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,2,10), dtype='category')
z.cat.categories = ['male', 'female']

a = pd.Series(np.random.randint(20,60,10), dtype='category')

data = pd.DataFrame({'risk':x, 'smoking':y, 'sex':z, 'age':a})
print (data)
  age risk     sex smoking
0  24   no    male     yes
1  23  yes    male     yes
2  22   no  female      no
3  40   no  female     yes
4  59   no  female      no
5  22   no    male     yes
6  40   no  female      no
7  27  yes    male     yes
8  55  yes    male     yes
9  48   no    male      no
```

```
tmp = {'risk':'no', 'smoking':'yes', 'sex':'female'}
mask = pd.concat([data[x[0]].eq(x[1]) for x in tmp.items()], axis=1).all(axis=1)
print (mask)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
dtype: bool

df1 = data[mask]
print (df1)
 age risk     sex smoking
3  40   no  female     yes
```

```
L = [(x[0], x[1]) for x in tmp.items()]
print (L)
[('smoking', 'yes'), ('sex', 'female'), ('risk', 'no')]

L = pd.concat([data[x[0]].eq(x[1]) for x in tmp.items()], axis=1)
print (L)
  smoking    sex   risk
0    True  False   True
1    True  False  False
2   False   True   True
3    True   True   True
4   False   True   True
5    True  False   True
6   False   True   True
7    True  False  False
8    True  False  False
9   False  False   True
```

**Timings**:

`len(data)=1M`.

```
N = 1000000
np.random.seed(123)
x = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,2,N), dtype='category')
x.cat.categories = ['no', 'yes']
y = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,2,N), dtype='category')
y.cat.categories = ['no', 'yes']
z = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,2,N), dtype='category')
z.cat.categories = ['male', 'female']

a = pd.Series(np.random.randint(20,60,N), dtype='category')

data = pd.DataFrame({'risk':x, 'smoking':y, 'sex':z, 'age':a})

#[1000000 rows x 4 columns]
print (data)


tmp = {'risk':'no', 'smoking':'yes', 'sex':'female'}


In [133]: %timeit (data[pd.concat([data[x[0]].eq(x[1]) for x in tmp.items()], axis=1).all(axis=1)])
10 loops, best of 3: 89.1 ms per loop

In [134]: %timeit (data.query(' and '.join(["{} == '{}'".format(k,v) for k,v in tmp.items()])))
1 loop, best of 3: 237 ms per loop

In [135]: %timeit (pd.merge(pd.DataFrame(tmp, index =[0]), data.reset_index()).set_index('index'))
1 loop, best of 3: 256 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a look up data frame from the dictionary and then do an inner join with the `data` which will have the same effect as `query`:

```
from pandas import merge, DataFrame
merge(DataFrame(tmp, index =[0]), data)
```

[image]

Comment: And if you wanted to preserve the index?

Comment: @Ianery `merge(DataFrame(tmp, index =[0]), data.reset_index()).set_index('index')` works, not ideal though.

Answer (score 2):

You could build a boolean vector that checks those attributes.  Probably a better way though:

```
df[risk == 'no' and smoking == 'yes' and sex == 'female' for (age, risk, sex, smoking) in df.itertuples()]
```

Comment: invalid syntax: complains about "for"

Answer (score 1):

I think you can could use the `to_dict` method on your dataframe, and then filter using a list comprehension:

```python
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'age':[28, 29], 'sex':["M", "F"], 'smoking':['y', 'n']})
print df
tmp = {'age': 28, 'smoking': 'y', 'sex': 'M'}

print pd.DataFrame([i for i in df.to_dict('records') if i == tmp])


>>>    age sex smoking
0   28   M       y
1   29   F       n

   age sex smoking
0   28   M       y
```

You could also convert tmp to a series:

```
ts = pd.Series(tmp)

print pd.DataFrame([i[1] for i in df.iterrows() if i[1].equals(ts)])
```